# Does saying 'then' after 'sorry' imply reluctance?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

`A` did something wrong but didn't realize it. `B` explained to `A` why what (s)he did was wrong. Then `A` said: "Sorry then". Is `A` really sorry?

Literally, "sorry then" (in my head) means in light of the new information, I am sorry. But my friend say the 'then' after the sorry means `A` said it reluctantly and (s)he is not really sorry.

So which is it? Do you have any more examples of when placing 'then' after a statement makes it imply the speaker's reluctance?

Comment: Unconditional apologies are rare, but good when they come along. I can imagine someone being sincere in saying, I'm sorry, then (implying acknowledgement of hurt done.) But I can also imagine it tossed off insincerely. The context, tone, expression, (body language) all matter.

Comment: @medica picking your brains...can you think of another example of when 'then' denotes reluctance?

Comment: Good question. All ok: See you, then, good luck then... maybe, *do it yourself, then.* And certainly, *You go first then.* But generally, I don't think *then* implies hesitancy. Maybe someone else can give you a better answer. :)

Comment: @medica thank you for your comments! The 'Do it yourself, then' sounds a little hostile to me. It is these context to which I refer to.

Comment: @dayuloli - but does it sound less hostile if it is just "Do it yourself"?  Both may show some asperity, but saying one is more than the other is a bit dicey.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how it could imply reluctance. But in the context 'then' could mean 'in that case', now that I know I did something wrong.

From Oxford English dictionary 'then' can means:
...
a. In that case; in those circumstances; if that be (or were) the fact; if so; when that happens. Often correlative to if or when. what then? (ellipt.) what happens (or would happen) in that case? what of that?
...

Comment: Thank you for your response, I understand what it literally means, but I'm looking for possible meaning behind the use of the word.

Comment: I tried google to find examples of the expression, but I couldn't get something more than the literal meaning. Sorry